# useEffect does not call when deps changes if using useSelector from react-redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

Here is my code example:

```js
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { updateMyData } from '../features';

const MyComponent = ({ list }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  // select myData from redux store
  const someData = useSelector((state) => state.myData);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // YOU WILL NOT SEE THIS LINE
    console.log('useEffect', someData);
  }, [someData]);
  // each time I can see newly changed data
  console.log('someData', someData);

  const handleClick = () => {
    const newData = list.find((l) => l.name === 'myName');
    // change myData, in my case it is some pagination, and I select newData from existing list
    dispatch(updateMyData(newData));
  };

  return <div onClick={handleClick}>{'Hello world!'}</div>;
};
```

In my case, I have a list of items, and when I press some button change it (in redux store).
**someData** changes, **MyComponent** rerenders but **useEffect** wasn't called.

**useEffect** was called only during the first render.

Why useEffect hadn't called when its deps were changed?

Comment: Maybe add a log into the `const someData = useSelector((state) => state.myData);` function to see when it's updating. Also maybe try importing React like `import { useEffect } from 'react'`

Comment: Robert got it. But to perfect fits to your code only:  import React

Comment: But if imports are fine, there are some things to check: 1 - there is this reducer connected to store? 2 - the action really affect desired reducer?

Comment: If I add console.log(someData) after useEffect I can see changed data, everything works fine. Component rerenders each time when someData changes.

Comment: Can you add the definition of `updateMyData` action creator to the description ?

Comment: It doesn't matter, someData changes each time, everything works ok, except useEffect

Comment: It matters. Probably you are returning a mutated obj from action creaetor

Comment: It is strange, I did a test with a similar situation than yours and the console appeared. Can you create a reproducible example?

Comment: I'd say it should work or rather: it works everytime I use this pattern. I'd also like to see a minimal reproducible example then.

Comment: I use @reduxjs/toolkit, maybe problem here..... Creating an example is very difficultly... I will try

Comment: I create such an example and it is work - https://codesandbox.io/s/try-to-reproduce-useeffect-issue-jisycu. Maybe the problem in my project... I don't have any ideas